# C# textbox1_keydown event with "static" variable

Tags: c#

Hi I just wrote a method for keydown event of a textbox. The problem here is: I need a variable to be "static", that is, the change of the variable could be reserved for the next run of the method. I tried to use static but it seems only static method could allow such declaration.

Can I ask what can I do to solve the problem? Thank you very much!

```
private  void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter) return;

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

            if (textBox1.Text == "00000000")
            {

                typeselected = true;
                type = 0;

            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "00000001")
            {
                typeselected = true;
                type = 1;

            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "00000002")
            {
                typeselected = true;
                type = 2;
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "00000003")
            {
                typeselected = true;
                type = 3;

            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "00000004")
            {
                typeselected = true;
                type = 4;

            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "00000005")
            {
                typeselected = true;
                type = 5;

            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "00000006")
            {
                typeselected = true;
                type = 6;

            }


            else if (typeselected) { typeselected = excel0(textBox1.Text, type); }
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of an [instance variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691164%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> An instance variable of a class comes into existence when a new
>   instance of that class is created, and ceases to exist when there are
>   no references to that instance and the instance's destructor (if any)
>   has executed.

Something like

```
private int tada = 0;
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    tada++;
}
```

Comment: Hi astander, thank you very much! It is working. but since I want to alter and use the variables only within the textbox1_keydown() method but not somewhere else, is there any modifications can be made ? I uploaded some codes, I would want the typeselected and type variable to be reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Make your static variable a class instance variable, rather than a method variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods (without the keyword static) can reference static class variables:

```
class X
{
    static int A;

    public void SetA(int newA)
    {
        A = newA;
    }
}
```